# What is the German Word For "Mortgagee?"

Tags: translation, single-word-request

The word I'm inclined to use is "Hypothekar," which refers to a lender of a property. But a German teacher preferred "Gläubiger" which, I believe, refers to a "general" creditor. Which of these (or a third term) is correct?

The context is my translation of another song from the stage (not movie) version of the Sound of Music.

http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/thesoundofmusic/howcanlovesurvive.htm

> No (little) shack do you share with me.
> We do not flee from a mortgagee.
> Nary a care in the world have we,
> How can love survive?
>
> Keine Hütte teilst du mit mir.
> Wir fliehen von keinem Hypothekar/Gläubiger
> Keine Sorgen haben wir,
> Wie kann die Liebe überleben?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two equally used German translations for *"Mortgagee"*:

> Hypothekengläubiger/Hypothekengläubigerin (*f.* in case it is a bank)
>   Hypothekar

In the context of a song lyric I would not recommend to use these more technical terms that are not so well known to people outside the finance businesses. Translating *"Mortgagee"* simply with *"Gläubiger"* is perfectly fine (though less precise).

Comment: "Hypothekennehmer" is a composite word I've read once or twice as well.

Answer (score 8):

It would be "Hypothekar" (with a, not e), but no one will ever use it if not in a legal/financial context. So the more general "Gläubiger" would be IMHO a better choice. (oh, Takkat was faster than me...)

Another remark: "verteilen" doesn't fit in this context - simply "teilen" is a better choice here.

Comment: @takkat: thanks for the corrections, both helpful, and both what I wanted out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

In a song context, even Gläubiger is rather technical and prone to misunderstanding. Compare a German pop song

> "Finanz und Banken steigen mir drauf, die Rechnung, die geht sowieso nicht auf".

The lenders are simply called Finanz for Finanzamt (IRS) and Banken (banks who are the mortgagees).

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes "Hypothekar" is the most precise translation, but "Gläubiger" is the word most commonly in use because the former one is professional language of people working for banks or engaging in other financial business.